# Does the Textview.gettext return null?

Tags: android, null, textview

In the following code,

```
TextView textv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
```

when I call `textv.getText();` while the textview has nothing and is just declared does it returns a `charsequence`(not null) of what ? I don't get it

Answer (score 1):

`getText()` will not return null, it will return an empty string if there is no string written in, which is definitely not null

Comment: So this code `textv.setText(textv.getText()+"\n");` will return a new line right ?

Answer (score 1):

You can debug first to see if the textview is actually found in your activity/fragment.
Try doing if (texttv != null) and see what it shows. Most likely it is not found in your xml file.
You can also try setting dummy text right after initialization.
textv.setText("text set by code");
if you see the text in your textview, then you will know if its assigned or not.
Hope it helps!

Comment: So this code`textv.setText(textv.getText()+"\n");` will return a new line right ?

Comment: That code will take what's already written and add a linebreak (one more line). Normally you would be adding more text after the +"\n".